# Closure of Set of Solutions

Tags: analysis

Let A be the set defined by the inequalities $f_1(x)\geq 0, ..., f_n(x)\geq 0$, where $f_1,...,f_n$ are continuous functions defined on the whole line. Show that A is closed. Show that the set defined by $f_1(x)> 0, ..., f_n(x)>0$, is open.

Could someone prove this statement? I'm struggling in thinking of a way to relate limit-points and such to solutions of a set of inequalities.

Comment: Can you show it for a single function, i.e. the $n=1$ case? If so you know intersection of finitely many closed/open sets is closed/open.

Comment: Remember that the continuity of a function means it has the  property that $f^{-1}(U) $ is open for every open set $U$. Also consider the open sets $(0,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,0)$.